# Using sitemap_generator with different locale urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sitemap

I have a multilingual site coded in Rails. I use the gem sitemap_generator to generate the sitemaps. The problem is that I only generate the url's for once language. I change the default language of the site using a params[:locale].

This is my sitemap.rb

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.dominio.com"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do
     Product.find_each do |product|
       add url_for(:controller => 'products', :action => 'show', :id => product, :host => '', :only_path => true), :lastmod => product.updated_at
     end
end
```

How can I generate url's for the en, es and it locales? With this code it only generates the default locale (en).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[:en, :es].each do |locale|
  Product.find_each do |product|
    add url_for(:controller => 'products', :action => 'show', :id => product, :host => '', :only_path => true, :locale => locale), :lastmod => product.updated_at
  end
end
```

Comment: If you save locale to session, it may be convenient to add to routes something like  http://host/:locale/... and use it in sitemap

Answer (score 0):

I suggest store locale field in product model like :locale (string) and then you can add where condition.

like this:

```
[:en, :es].each do |locale|
    Product.where(locale: locale).find_each do |product|
        #do something
    end
end
```